# "Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter." Error? Problem with django-simplejwt

Tags: python, django, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am trying to work with djangorestframework-simplejwt and trying to follow this tutorial:

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tutorials/django-aws/rest-api-jwt/

Currently I'm at this point where I have a superuser account already set up and I'm using Postman to send a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token` to access the TokenObtainPairView view from simplejwt.

But I keep on getting this problem:

[image]

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.
When I do to Headers and add in the key "Content-Disposition" and value "attachment; filename=file". I get a different problem where my body is populated with the username and password but the response keeps on saying the field is required even though I provided in Body.

[image]

This is my code for urls.py

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
    TokenVerifyView
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
]
```

I'm not sure what is going on and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you try sending the username and password as raw json (instead of x-www-form-urlencoded) and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Hey I tried that and that was the issue thank you!~